# Dotdeb alternatives for Ruby or Python?

Tags: package-management, python, repository, ruby

I really like [Dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/about/), but it doesn't include packages for Ruby and Python. While I could build my own repository, I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel (and then be forced to drive). Are there any *good* public repositories like Dotdeb for other languages like Ruby or Python? Dotdeb's selling point for me is the immediacy (the PHP 5.5 package was realeased on the day 5.5 was released) and the reliability – it just works.

Comment: I tried Googling this and nothing seemed relevant...

Comment: Please don't use comments to add additional information, but instead **edit** your question. :)

Comment: I haven't found a good alternative - however, the bluebox group did have some nice stuff a few months back, dunno if they still keep it up-to-date or not. Most ruby people compile from scratch, for various reasons.